# 'argparse' has no 'ArgumentParser' member

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Python newbie question...
I am using Python3.6 on macOS and I have installed argpase using

> sudo pip3 install argparse

pip3 list does not list argparse but I can see it is installed because "help("argparse") in python3 displays the documentation.

But when I write the following simple test program I receive the error: " 'argparse' has no 'ArgumentParser' member"

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()
```

Ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `argparse` module is built into Python 3.6.  Also, you likely have another module/namespace somewhere that is causing a conflict - try `print(argparse)` immediately after the import and see where that path leads.

Comment: By any chance did you create a file called `argparse.py` ?

Comment: OMG - what a dumb @r53 - yes I did. That was the problem. Thanks metatoaster & khelwood. It never clicked that my module was creating a conflicting namespace. An important "learning python" tip for me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, we know that the issue was that the user created a file called `argparse.py`, which shadowed the standard library `argparse`.  An easy way to detect if this is the case is to print out the file path location of a module.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> print(argparse.__file__)
>>> # alternatively you can use inspect
>>> import inspect
>>> print(inspect.getsourcefile(argparse))
```

This will show where the file is located. It would be easy to debug the problem when you see the file path that is being used.

Comment: Just curious, what would inspect do here that `.__file__` can't?

Comment: @BradSolomon Absolutely nothing.  I was pre-empting the people that would say "you can also use `inspect`!".